# compare int and return 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare these 2 fields,

```
select(@var1-@var2-@var3-@var4),@var6
```

and in my mind, I have something like this

```
if (@var1-@var2-@var3-@var4)>@var6
then return 1
else return 0
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: those variales are int, they've been previously declared and set.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select case when (@var1-@var2-@var3-@var4)>@var6 then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: @taby No worries.  We all get blocked from time-to-time  :)